# Android: how to change activity elements when calling onDestroy()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

when I call context.stopService(myService), I would like to do some setEnabled(true) or setEnabled(false) on some buttons in my android activity.

My question is: How can I an activity and change it from onDestroy() function in the service?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly, but if you want to set up a communication between your service and activity you should read about [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html). It provides the interface through which both of them can pass data to each other.

Comment: Hi Alex, yes I want my service to communicate with my activity, I want actually to enable or disable some buttons in the activity from a function in my service.

Comment: So I think this is how you should do it. Extend `IntentService` (it's easier then `Service`) and then override `onBind()`.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I will have a look on it.

Comment: Yes Alex, thank you for your answer, I closed the question as resolved!